# Lua: "attempt to concatenate global" Error in MPV

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a little script to output filetags in mpv. My script looks like this:

```
require 'os'
require 'string'

function displayTrack()
    currentTrack = mp.get_property("metadata/by-key/Title")
    currentArtist = mp.get_property("metadata/by-key/Artist")
    currentAlbum = mp.get_property("metadata/by-key/Album")
    print(currentArtist)
    print(currentAlbum)
    print(currentTrack)

    if currentTrack == nil then
        os.execute("terminal-notifier -title '" .. currentArtist .. "' -message 'Unknown Title'")
    else
        os.execute("terminal-notifier -title '" .. currentArtist .. "' -message '" .. currentAlbum .. " - " .. currentTrack .. "'")
    end
end

mp.observe_property("eof-reached", "bool", displayTrack)
```

Catching the tags and printing them works with every tested title. But if i want to uncomment the 5 lines starting with "if currentTrack == nil ..." so it also dislpays a native notification i get the LUA error:

```
/Users/marcel/.config/mpv/scripts/notification.lua:15: attempt to concatenate global 'currentArtist' (a nil value)
```

Can somebody tell me why i can print the string but not forward it to the `os.execute`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not `os.execute`, it is concatenation - `..` - that can't work with `nil`. And yes, you can print standalone `nil` just fine. In your case not only `currentTrack` is `nil`, but `currentArtist` too, so you can't build a string with it. Consider if you even need those entries where you don't have value for `currentArtist` and either skip them, provide alternative `if` branch to do something else or provide some default in concatenation. Usual idiom is `(currentArtist or '')` - here your default will be empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but my exact problem is, that currentArtist is not nil if i comment out the os.execute part. Printing the values works every time. But with the os.execute the script works only one time and after that i get the lua error.

Comment: @diepfanne. It IS. And that's what Lua is telling you. Sorry, it can't be both nil and not nil at same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if currentTrack == nil then
    os.execute("terminal-notifier -title '" .. currentArtist .. "' -message 'Unknown Title'")
```

If this branch gets executed, `currentTrack` is nil, thus the concatenation fails as stated by the error message.

Just get rid of the concatenation all together:

```
  if currentTrack == nil then
    os.execute("terminal-notifier -title -message 'Unknown Title'")
```

Comment: Except that `currentTrack` isn't used anywhere in that particular branch. And removing the concatenation means failing to pass the `-title` parameter its required argument.